# R: Assign value to a character row from dataframe

Tags: r

Hi how can I assign value to the 1st column characters that is based on the 2nd column. See my sample dataframe below.

```
> Code <- c('A','B','C','D','E')
> Value <- c(1.23,1.4,1.55,1.67,1.3)
> ds <- data.frame(Code, Value)
> ds
  Code Value
1    A  1.23
2    B  1.40
3    C  1.55
4    D  1.67
5    E  1.30
```

Now for example when I type "A" in the R console it should have a value of 1.23. Not error as shown below.

```
> A
Error: object 'A' not found
```

Desired output is.

```
> A
[1] 1.23
```

It should also work in Codes B to E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having many global variables is not recommended, however, here is a way :

```
list2env(split(ds$Value, ds$Code), .GlobalEnv)

A
#[1] 1.23
B
#[1] 1.4
```

Answer (score 2):

And yet another way, here using `assign()` and a `for` loop:

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(ds))) {
  assign(ds$Code[i], ds$Value[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using `setNames` + `list2env`

```
list2env(with(ds, setNames(as.list(Value), Code)), .GlobalEnv)
```

or `eval` + `str2expression` (this option is NOT recommended)

```
eval(str2expression(do.call(paste, c(ds, sep = "<-", collapse = ";"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are asking for (I wouldn't add all the rows as global variables). Instead this solutions keeps your  `data.frame` as a `data.table` with a key which allows you to retrieve the relevant row in a concise way:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(ds)
setkey(ds, Code)

ds["B", Value]
# [1] 1.4
```

You could also use a named list:

```r
x <- setNames(as.list(ds$Value), ds$Code)
x$B
# [1] 1.4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `attach` to access values of a named list.

```
attach(setNames(as.list(ds$Value), ds$Code))
A
#[1] 1.23
D
#[1] 1.67

#And remove it again with
detach()
```

Or you can use `assign` in `mapply`

```
mapply(assign, ds$Code, ds$Value, MoreArgs = list(envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

or with `Vectorize`

```
Vectorize(assign, c("x", "value"))(ds$Code, ds$Value, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```